# Azure web job failing to execute after timeout

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

some of my continuous running web job function(random) show message of `Timeout value of 00:30:00 exceeded by function '<myfunction>' (Id: '<id>'). Initiating cancellation`.

after this message this function will not execute itself until and unless manually stop and start the azure web job.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of job is it, what triggers it? (if its an interval trigger on a continuous job - that is likely your problem).
Please also read this before you update your question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

> some of my continuous running web job function(random) show message of `Timeout value of 00:30:00 exceeded by function '<myfunction>' (Id: '<id>'). Initiating cancellation`.

Based on your error, I found the related code from **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host** under [FunctionExecutor.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/3696dd28df66996b1adcc0697f0d0f88f865cb64/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Executors/FunctionExecutor.cs) as follows:

```html
internal static void OnFunctionTimeout(System.Timers.Timer timer, FunctionDescriptor method, Guid instanceId, TimeSpan timeout, bool timeoutWhileDebugging,
    TraceWriter trace, ILogger logger, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource, Func<bool> isDebuggerAttached)
{
    timer.Stop();

    bool shouldTimeout = timeoutWhileDebugging || !isDebuggerAttached();
    string message = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "Timeout value of {0} exceeded by function '{1}' (Id: '{2}'). {3}",
        timeout.ToString(), method.ShortName, instanceId,
        shouldTimeout ? "Initiating cancellation." : "Function will not be cancelled while debugging.");

    trace.Error(message, null, TraceSource.Execution);
    logger?.LogError(message);

    trace.Flush();

    // Only cancel the token if not debugging
    if (shouldTimeout)
    {
        // only cancel the token AFTER we've logged our error, since
        // the Dashboard function output is also tied to this cancellation
        // token and we don't want to dispose the logger prematurely.
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```

I assumed that you specified the `TimeoutAttribute` for your function as follows:

[image]

I would recommend you could use a `CancellationToken` parameter in your function and it would be canceled whenever a timeout occurs or host shutdown, and you could exit your function gracefully as follows:

[image]

Comment: Check your code and try to solve this issue. Any concerns, feel free to let us know.