# Handle timeouts of Node Function Apps

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-function-app

I created an Azure Function App with a Node runtime, which works properly on local and manually created cloud environments.

But when it becomes deployed via Azure Pipelines, it writes a message via `context.log` and seems working but finally it raises Timeout error.

> Timeout value of 00:05:00 exceeded by function 'Functions.<...>' (Id: '<...>'). Initiating cancellation.

I guess, that there is some blocking Node expression because of misconfiguration, but there is no further context logged by Application Insights.

There is a way to handle the cancelation event within your Function App to provide some Node runtime information (e.g. via `SIGINT` callbacks)?

Comment: I found a quite similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59146025/846163.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce this issue but failed. But I got some similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543191/azure-web-job-failing-to-execute-after-timeout) and noticed we can set `functionTimeout` value in `host.json` file. How about trying it.